# How to improve training accuracy of DCGAN

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, keras

I trained a Deep Convolutional Generative Adversarial Network. The training accuracy of the generator did not turn out very well and the training loss was 10.1567 after 10 hours of training. What should I do to improve the accuracy ? Should I increase the batch size for each epoch ? Add more layers ? Add more nodes to each layer ?

I have used all the practices recommended for a good GAN such as stride instead of pooling and batch normalisation in both models.

Complete source code :- https://github.com/tanmay-edgelord/DCGAN-keras/tree/master

The results from the generator are in the 'Generate_image.ipynb' notebook. Please ask for any other details that are needed.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. The question appears, at least to me, to be about a concept in machine learning and not simply "on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a whole slew of tips you can implement: https://github.com/soumith/ganhacks

A few specific tips which apply to you:

- Use LeakyReLu instead of Relu
- Don't mix real and generated content in batches: construct separate batches for real and generated content respectively
- Save checkpoints of your models and mix in older versions of the generator and discriminator every couple of generations
- Instead of using straight binary 0/1 for your discriminator target variable, add noise to the discriminator target variable
- Use ConvTranspose2d for upsampling
- Add dropout
- Don't assume you have a good training schedule: check in on the norm of the gradient and visualize generated samples periodically.